# Checkmate in two moves

Tags: checkmate, problems

White to play and checkmate in two moves.

```
[fen "5Kbk/6pp/6P1/8/7R/8/8/8 w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Is it possible? If so, please write a solution.

Comment: This is the third position given in one of the answers to a zugzwang question a day or two ago - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21311/what-is-zugzwang-in-chess/21312?s=4|0.0000#21312. This kind of copy& paste question is not clever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Rh6

This puts Black in Zugzwang.

If 1...gxh6, 2.g7#

If Black moves the Bishop, 2.Rxh7#

Comment: And it has to be 1 Rh6; any other move of the rook on the h-file would enable Black to push the h7 pawn and prevent 2 Rh7#.