# What is the difference between a waiting move and zugzwang?

Tags: terminology, zugzwang

I can't see the difference between a waiting move and zugzwang.

Comment: Very Closely Related: [What is zugzwang in chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/21311/26335)

Comment: Did you mean to say zugwang here, or zwischenzug?

Comment: Maybe the translation of the german word "Zugzwang" helps to see the difference? In games, it refers to the general rule of being compelled ("gezwungen sein", noun: "Zwang") to make a move ("ziehen" in this context, noun: "Zug") when it is your turn -- skipping is not an option allowed by the rules of the game. From that point of view, you are always in Zugzwang when you play chess and it is your turn. Having said that, the word comes up mostly when moving weakens your position: "Can I skip my turn?"/"Kann ich passen?" -- "No, the rules compel you to make a move"/"Nein, es herrscht Zugzwang!"

Comment: It would have helped if you had written what you think these terms mean.

Answer (score 15):

Zugzwang is when one side would like to "pass" but cannot. With a waiting move, you essentially do "pass". A waiting move *could* lead to zugzwang if one side has the ability to play them and the other does not, but this is by no means necessary.

An opponent might have their own waiting moves (in which case the game could be drawn by repetition unless one side decides to do something meaningful) or they might have a different evaluation of the position and decide to simply proceed with their plan.

For example, one side might play a waiting move to see which side the opponent castles on, but the opponent may well think that the benefits of castling right then outweigh the drawbacks of giving the first player that information.

Answer (score 8):

A waiting move is a move to wait and see what your opponent will do.

If you are in zugzwang then all moves worsen your position.

Comment: Zugzwang is not having only bad moves but especially if **making a move** worsens your position

Comment: "If you are in zugzwang then you have only bad moves" is correct but incomplete; I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Minot I don't see the different between a `bad move` and a `move that worsens your position`   I edited my response to include your wording since it was not clear.

Comment: @MichaelWest - I understand where you're coming from, but at least in my mind there's a difference.  To me, a "bad move" (in the way I think people usually mean that) is a mistake - an error.  Whereas, in zugzwang, there's no error - it's just that there aren't any moves available (at all) that aren't harmful to your position.  There's no "error" in that case - it's just that there aren't any decent choices available.

Comment: @patbarron that makes sense to me.  Glad I changed the wording :)

Comment: The new wording is missing the word "only." Or, better yet: "all moves worsen your position."

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon changed.  That is clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Compressing your thoughts makes for a better master.

Comment: I don't think that the edit fixes the issue. The value of a position is the value of your best move. It's not possible for every move to worsen your position; your best move preserves the value of your position, by definition.

Comment: @Acccumulation: All moves lead to a position that is worse than the present arrangement of pieces would be if the opponent were on move.

Answer (score 3):

The former is a *move* which passes the initiative on to the opponent.

The latter is a *position* where that initiative is a burden, and all moves are detrimental to the player with the move.